# SMTP : Could not authenticate

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

```
<?php
include_once('include/connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$contact=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$comments=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);

/*
echo var_dump($name);
echo var_dump($contact);
echo var_dump($email);
echo var_dump($comments);
*/

$fdate=date("d/m/Y");



$date = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a");
//echo date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time());

$query = "INSERT INTO `form_entry`(`name`, `contact`, `email`,  `comments`) 
        VALUES ('$name', '$contact', '$email', '$comments')";
//echo var_dump($query);
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database: '.mysql_error());


//SEND CONFIRMATION EMAIL
        require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $message= "
        <br /><br />
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
        --  Name      :   $name                                            <br>
        --  Contact   :   $contact                                         <br>
        --  Email ID  :   $email                                           <br>
        --  Comments  :   $comments                                        <br>
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------       -------------------------           
                   ";
            $subject = "Enquiry from $name";
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP(); 
            //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
            $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
            $mail->Port       = 465;             
            $mail->Username="xyz@gmail.com";  
            $mail->Password="abc123@@!";            
            $mail->SetFrom('xyz@gmail.com','xyz ');
            $mail->FromName="xyz";
            $mail->AddAddress($email);
            $mail->AddReplyTo("xyz@gmail.com","xyz ");
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = "Hello Sir/Madam,";
            $mail->IsHTML($message);
            $mail->Send();


echo "<script>alert('Data Saved Successfully');</script>";
mysql_close($connection);
}
?>
```

Output : " SMTP Error : Could not authenticate "
It's gmail authentication I'm trying.
ID & Password used to verify are surely perfect.
Checked the SMTP server settings from Google, Looks same.
I checked with other posts but didn't solve my problem.
Pls help for the same! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete example, you're using an old version of PHPMailer and you haven't read the docs, or what the duplicates of this question say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the below code

```
        $to = to@gmail.com;
        $from = 'info@test.com';
        $name = 'test.com';
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host = 'bh-24.webhostbox.net';
        $mail->Port = 465;  
        $mail->Username = 'info@test.com';  
        $mail->Password = '1234#';   

        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From="info@test.com";
        $mail->FromName="test.com";
        $mail->Sender=$from; // indicates ReturnPath header
        $mail->AddReplyTo($from, $FromName); // indicates ReplyTo headers
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $msg  = "this is a test message";
        $mail->Body = $msg;
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        $mail->Send();
```

Comment: Dipak Thanks for your help! Your example is indeed correct ! It was just a glitch from google account. I had to enable "Allow Less Secure Apps" in my google account.